# Passing arguments to the task in the Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I need a Spring Cloud Dataflow Task to pass on the parameters during startup. While I found out how to run it in Spring Data Flow Shell (e. g.: task create my-composed-task --definition "mytaskapp --displayMessage=hello"), I don't know how to refer to these parameters in Java code. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: These properties get bound during context build time. You have to add them as properties in your application using @ ConfigurationProperties or @ Value annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest example can be found in Spring Cloud Task [`timestamp`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/timestamp/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/task/timestamp) sample.

Here, the application prints the current timestamp when it starts; however, there's also the ability to override the format of the timestamp through the [`setFormat(String format)`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/timestamp/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/task/timestamp/TimestampTaskProperties.java#L38-L40) function.

For instance, you can create and launch the application as:

> task create myTaskDefinition --definition "timestamp --format='yyyy'"
>
> task launch myTaskDefinition

When the launch is successful, instead of the default `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`, you will see the resulting output in `yyyy` format.